# Need help understanding code

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi all i am new in jquery

this code in book jQuery in action page 219

why he use `.end()` method

and thanks :)

```
(function($){
$.fn.setReadOnly = function(readonly) {
return this.filter('input:text')
.attr('readOnly',readonly)
.css('opacity', readonly ? 0.5 : 1.0)
.end();
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jQuery function should return `this` to allow chaining.

Using `.end()` he undoes `.filter('input:text')` so finally he's returning the `this` jQuery object.